# instanciation of a ReadOnlyCollection

Tags: c#

I have a problem with coverage of a ReadOnlyCollection.

I'm using two collections , one which will be populated with an Access database, then sorted and copied in a ReadOnlyCollection
with

```
public static  List<ToponymeGeoDb> ListeToponymesGeoDb = new List<ToponymeGeoDb>();

public static ReadOnlyCollection<ToponymeGeoDb> roListeToponymesGeoDb = new ReadOnlyCollection<ToponymeGeoDb>(ListeToponymesGeoDb);
```

Once populated I transfer the data with

```
ToponymeGeoDb.roListeToponymesGeoDb =new ReadOnlyCollection<ToponymeGeoDb>(ToponymeGeoDb.ListeToponymesGeoDb);
```

At this stage my roListeToponymesGeoDb contains my data but when I try to use it in another part of my program it is empty!!

As it is declared as a static member I don't understand what is happening.

Comment: You don't need to "transfer data over". Any changes to ListeToponymesGeoDb automatically gets reflected in the ReadOnlyCollection. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If roListeToponymesGeoDb is empty, then ListeToponymesGeoDb is empty. Check that ListeToponymesGeoDb is being populated properly.

Comment: Just cast into a `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` in a getter property.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a private list of items, and expose a property of `IReadOnlyCollection` instead.

```
public struct Topo { }  

public class Foo
{
    // Private list of types. This is actual storage of the data.
    // It is inialized to a new empty list by the constructor.
    private List<Topo> InnerItems { get; } = new List<Topo>();

    // Example on how to modify the list only through this class
    // Methods have access to `InnerList`
    public void Add(Topo item) { InnerItems.Add(item); }

    // Outside of the class only `Items` is exposed
    // This poperty casts the list as a readonly collection
    public IReadOnlyCollection<Topo> Items => InnerItems;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new Foo();

        foo.Add(new Topo());

        // foo.Items.Add() doesnt exist.

        foreach(var item in foo.Items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use instead the following:

```
    public IReadOnlyList<Topo> Items => InnerItems;
```

This gives you access to results by index also. Like `Items[0]` for the first item.